# Can't find the right Wordpress Catalyst Widget paddings

Tags: wordpress, widget

I'm tweaking our blog (www.CuerpoDeVerano.com) and can't find the right settings for the widget padding. The blog is in Wordpress with the Catalyst theme (basic Dynamik skin).

```
If you visit the site you'll see two cats to the right. Notice the blue title bars with a grey add-on that shouldn't be there. The blue rectangle should reach all the way to the edges.

The text, on the other hand, shouldn't reach the borders of the widget. I would like that to be padded left, right and bottom.

I'm also attaching a screen capture of the section I'm referring to.
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Answer from the Catalyst Theme forum: The CSS selector for this widget title is #sidebar-1 h4, #sidebar-2 h4, #ez-home-sidebar-1 h4

The image is set as a background property:

Code:
background: #E8E8E8 url(images/widgettitle.jpg) top center no-repeat;
This is set in Catalyst - Dynamik Options/Sidebars/Sidebar Heading Background

It's set to display in the center and not repeat. It has a diagonal gradient so this image is not suitable for repeating on either the x or y axis.

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer from the Catalyst Forum:

The CSS selector for this widget title is #sidebar-1 h4, #sidebar-2 h4, #ez-home-sidebar-1 h4 
The image is set as a background property: Code: background: #E8E8E8 url(images/widgettitle.jpg) top center no-repeat; This is set in Catalyst - Dynamik Options/Sidebars/Sidebar Heading Background It's set to display in the center and not repeat. It has a diagonal gradient so this image is not suitable for repeating on either the x or y axis.